# dt.Tablename="demoproject"; is not working in Web service After Hosting It

Tags: iis

The web service GetEmployeDetails(string empid) method perfactly working in localhost but after publishing it and another windows application where we use that method there data is nothing return.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;


namespace TCTimeTrackerWS.Employee
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Employee
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://192.168.31.240/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Employee : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
       [WebMethod]
        public DataTable GetEmployeDetails(string empid)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = DBHelperClass.FilldataTableUsingQuery(@"Select firstname,lastname From  MST_Employee WHere employeid='"+empid+"'");
                dt.TableName = "empdetails";

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

In localhost this code is working fine but in IIS Express it is giving me an error  in  below line  dt.TableName = "empdetails";

It will giving me error :
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at TCTimeTrackerWS.GetProject_webservice.GetProject.GetProjectByEmployee(String employeeid) in E:\Work Space 2\tcprojs\WebService\TCTimeTrackerWS\TCTimeTrackerWS\GetProject_webservice\GetProject.asmx.cs:line 27

How to Resolve that? thanks in advance...

Comment: looks like null assigned to dt and hence error thrown.
add 'dt.TableName = "empdetails";' in if loop

Comment: ya that right # Abid Hussain but in local that's perfactly working so why it's giving me error after hosting ..